# Jquery $.ChangePage callback Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a website which is displayed in a Android Webview App.

I use JqueryMobile (1.10.2) and the ChangePage method in order to navigate through my website.
Pages ask a webservice so they can take time to be displayed.

I want to display a Toast (Android) during the page is loading.
It works, but I don't know how to know when my page is loaded

My question is:
It is possible to know when the page is loaded by the $.ChangePage method in order to hide my Android Toast ?

Here my code:

```
$('div.ui-page').swipeleft(function (e) {
    //$("#pop").popup("open");
    window.Android.showToast();
    $.mobile.changePage("mypage", {
        transition: "slide"
    });
})
```

Into my Android App (with @JavascriptInterface):

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void hideToast() {
    if(wait > 0) {
        wait--;
    }
    if(wait == 0) {
        montoast.cancel();
    }
}    

public void showToast() {
    wait++;
    montoast.setText("loading...");
    montoast.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery( ".selector" ).on( "pagechange", function( event ) { ... } )
```

This event is triggered after the changePage() request has finished loading the page into the DOM and all page transition animations have completed

[Explanation Of the Event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagechange/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but why I need to have a selector on my ChangePage ?

Comment: @user3136305 selector is just for having the pageid so that we can make a specific page to have an event listner on changePage.